# php PDO connect database via socks5 proxy

Tags: php, pdo, socks5

I'm trying to connect to a remote database(mysql, clickhouse, oracle) through PDO，i can't use ssh tunnel because of the Internet Policy of my company，i can only use socks proxy like 3proxy to transfer my db connect request, is there any way to connect db using php PDO via socks5 proxy?

i try use PDO like this, using custom socket context, but not work

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options, $context);
```

Comment: Do you get a specific error? Also we can't see your socks setup. Try to provide a [mre] of your issue

Comment: thanks, but $context argument do not support in PDO, i just imagine like that

Comment: It's not clear what you mean exactly. You're right there is no such option in PDO, but we don't know what you have put in your $context variable or why you consider it relevant to the issue. Again, please [edit] your question to provide a clear description of the setup and all the relevant code and configuration into. We cannot see your screen or read your mind. See also [ask]

Comment: P.s. have you considered the possibility that violating or bypassing your company's security policy without their knowledge might be a disciplinary offence? If you need this for a work purpose, you should ask them to unblock the port for you. If it's not for work then you should use your personal device for this task. They likely have such policies to ensure the integrity of the environment and will not thank you for opening another channel where information could go in and out (no matter how innocent your purpose might be)